# No network on freshly installed Debian

Tags: networking, debian, ethernet

I installed Debian Squeeze (using the cd1 image) without an Ethernet cable plugged in, telling the installer to "configure later" the network.

Now, when I boot, I have no network manager nor `ifconfig` (if I type that command in a terminal it replies: `command not found`, except as root where I see a `lo` interface).

How should I enable the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the list of recognized interfaces with an `/sbin/ifconfig -a`.

If you don't see any `eth*` interfaces, and you have an Ethernet adaptor installed, it wasn't detected.  These days this is quite rare *unless* you have a card needing a firmware image to be loaded.

Assuming you find an `eth0` interface, you want to issue an `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 up` to bring it up.  Then a `dhclient eth0` to get an IP via DHCP.  If you want to set an IP address manually it's `/sbin/ifconfig eth0 {ip address} netmask {net mask}`; you'll also want to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to point to your DNS servers (use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, which are Google's public DNS servers, if you are in a pinch.)

`apt-get` and all that should work now.

Next, type `man interfaces` which will explain how to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and get Debian to do all this automatically for you at next reboot.

Comment: Also, `ifconfig` is `/sbin/ifconfig` which isn't in a user's `PATH` on Debian. You will need to call it with the full path as a user.

Comment: You forgot to remove the first sentence as well.