# Cannot connect to network on Debian

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I have been working on this new freshly installed Debian machine for quite some time now trying to get the network going so I have internet. During the installation process for the network configuration I said I'll "configure it later" as it couldn't do it on its own. So here I am.

I have seen and tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/313258/no-network-on-freshly-installed-debian/1068462#1068462) question + answer, but no luck

**Let's get to it.**

I am unable to ping anything and I can't do "apt-get" and it's frustrating as hell.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
```

My /etc/resolv.conf contains:

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

I am extremely stuck and don't know the next course of action as I cannot find a way to figure this out. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

This is my `ifconfig -a` when I'm plugged in using an ethernet cable.

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:60:0c:82:76:d7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.73  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e60:cff:fe82:76d7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1539 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7425280 (7.0 MiB)  TX bytes:152728 (149.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9013 (8.8 KiB)  TX bytes:9013 (8.8 KiB)
```

Comment: Try to activate eth0 `ip link set eth0 up` and check the result `ip link show dev eth0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your tag indicates that you are trying to setup a wireless connection. This is not as straight-forward as connecting per cable. (You should try that first though - see Oleg's answer).

If you are using a wireless network card it is also likely you are running a notebook. You then should install a desktop (like GNOME, Cinnamon, KDE,...) and use the network-manager. (But you did not provide any details on your setup, so I am just guessing.)

List your network devices. This should look something like this:

```
% lspci | grep -e "Ethernet\|Network"
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

You mentioned a Lenovo Thinkpad (which model?) which also should have a Intel wireless adapter. Unfortunately do the Intel wireless adapters not work out of the box in Debian/Jessie. You need the `firmware-iwlwifi` package from the `non-free` section.

Check your apt-sources for `non-free` first:

```
deb     http://http.debian.net/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

(if you have a very new Thinkpad you might also have to activate `jessie-backports`).

And install `firmware-iwlwifi`:

```
apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Reboot you notebook and the wireless adapter should be visible in the network-manager in KDE.

But if you really want to go wireless by using the command line, here we go...

List your network devices. Should look like this:

```
% ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:dd:0e:68:43:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8d:dd:4b:04:15:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Bring up your wireless adapter:

```
ip link set wlan0 up
```

Find your wireless network (SSID):

```
iwlist wlan0 scanning
iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep ESSID # just shows the available SSIDs
```

I also assume you have WPA-PSK enabled so you must setup it up. Run

```
wpa_passphrase myessid secretsecret
```

and you'll get something like this:

```
network={
    ssid="myessid"
    #psk="secretsecret"
    psk=a022d0c8f88de93e4b53e5ee1c5d98cd4171a15bd44cde7499faa294ad795211
}
```

Then edit your `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid myessid
        wpa-psk a022d0c8f88de93e4b53e5ee1c5d98cd4171a15bd44cde7499faa294ad795211
```

Bring up the device with:

```
ifup wlan0
```

See:

- https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#Command_Line
- https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#WPA-PSK_and_WPA2-PSK

HTH

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. However I am running a Lenovo Thinkpad and I'm using KDE (as requested by from a friend). When I type "ip link", I only have the 1. lo and 2. eth0 showing up, I don't have wlan0 being displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Which Lenovo Thinkpad do you have? You might need `firmware-iwlwifi`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting in `/etc/network/interfaces` to get all nesseccary network data automatically from you router via DHCP:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then restart your interface as a root:

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Comment: I first tried this as requested from dpat, when I type "ifdown eth0" I get the message: "ifdown: interface eth0 not configured"

Comment: Well, check that you plugged an Ethernet cable to your PC and try `ifconfig eth0 down`. Then `Ifup eth0`. If nothing helps just reboot. And show `ifconfig -a` output, please.

Comment: Ok so its plugged in with an Ethernet cable and I tried it again and its working. How can I get it so I can connect to a wireless connection now? Btw thanks for the help!

Comment: Not at all, thanks to all who answered here. Show `ifconfig -a` to see if there are a wlan interface and follow instructions from dpat to set it up.

Comment: I have added my output of "ifconfig -a" to the original post (it was too long for the comment box lol). Also I see no wlan interface :(. How do I add one?

Comment: By the way, if you do not familiar to Linux, then you installed some desktop version of debian I guess. Desktop versions usually featured with something like Network Manager to ease network settings. May be you'd better to use graphical utilities rather then command line.

Comment: I am quite familiar with UNIX/Linux machines, however just not the network things as it's usually not an issue for me. Not in this case lol. I can't seem to find a Network Manager on my Debian machine. What wireless adapter should I install on my debian machine?

Comment: I can not guess what hardware capabilities are there in you PC. If your PC doesn't have builtin Wi-Fi adapter so you need some USB one. All steps for configuring Wi-Fi adapters are described here (I'm just duplicating dpat's weblinks): https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

Answer (score 0):

I belive there is many ways to do this here is one thing you could try.

First make sure you have a backup before you start elaborate

```
mv /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bak
```

then to edit the **interfaces**

`nano /etc/network/interfaces`

one example could be like this if's set to static:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0   
    network 192.168.0.0 
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
```

to restart the network interface:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```