# Cannot connect to internet after fresh install of debian

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

So , yesterday I did a fresh install of Debian 11 on my Dell Vostro 3480 , I got a DHCP issue during the configuration so I entered the IP and mask manually during at that time .

After that once the installation got completed , I was able to see that I wasn't getting any icon of wi-fi or I was not able to connect to my home modem .

I did the following :

**lspci output**

```
01:00.0 Ethernet Controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co. , Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network Controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
```

**ifconfig**

```
bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

**ip addr**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
   link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
   inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever 
2: enpls0:  <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:d0:50:44:76:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**route -n**

```
bash: route: command not found
```

**ip route**

[Nothing is shown]

I was able to see [similar issues were posted earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/1068469/cannot-connect-to-network-on-debian#:%7E:text=Well%2C%20check%20that%20you%20plugged,ifconfig%20%2Da%20output%2C%20please) on here , and i referred those threads completely

So , I download the `firmware-iwlwifi` file [from here](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-nonfree-amd64/firmware-iwlwifi_20210315-3_all.deb.html) on my usb drive and then i mounted the file to another directory using the below command

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usb
```

After this , I went under **/etc/apt/sources.list** and added "non-free" at the end of the below predefined lines so it looked something like this :

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
```

After this , I went into /media/usb and then ran the below command

**sudo dpkg -i firmware-iwlwifi_20210315-3_all.deb**

```
Selecting previously unselected package firmware iwlwifi
(Reading database ... 143298 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack firmware-iwlwifi_20210315-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-iwlwifi (20210315-3) ...
Setting up firmware-iwlwifi (20210315-3) ...
```

**sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
firmware-iwlwifi is already the newest version (20210315-3).
0 upgraded , 0 newly installed , 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded .
```

After this when I reboot my device (as it is recommended) and then when I log back in again and then when i type the below command :

```
lsmod | grep iwl
```

[Nothing comes up]

After this , when I type the below command , I'm able to see the NetworkManager is up .

**sudo systemctl status NetworkManager**

```
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-01-18 09:16:54 GMT; 35min ago
    Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Main PID: 594 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 9322)
    Memory: 13.0M
    CPU: 721ms 
    CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
          594 /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```

I am quite stuck on this issue right now , Any suggestion or help regarding this would extremely helpful . As , currently it's not possible to access internet from this machine right now .

Thank you !

Comment: iwlwifi is a package of drivers or firmware for Intel WNICs. Your WNIC is not made by Intel. Yours is made by QCA (Qualcomm Atheros). You need to follow Debian instructions for getting the Ath9k drivers (or whatever supports your QCA9377) installed.